# Is there a way to handle the "scheme does not have a registered handler." error from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, native

Scenario:

I have an app on my desktop which has a URL scheme registered `apple://`. On Chrome, I go to google.com and type following in the page's console:

```js
window.open('apple://launch')
```

At this point a new Chrome window opens and I see the dialog to allow opening of this app. On the google.com's console log I see the log message
`Launched external handler for 'apple://launch'.`

Now I try following code

```js
window.open('banana://launch')
```

A new Chrome window opens but it can't navigate because this URL scheme is not registered. In the Google.com's console, I see the following error log
`Failed to launch 'banana://launch' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.`

I tried to add try/catch around the window open but that didn't give me anything, as expected, because the window is opening properly.

My question is: How can I catch the error that google.com seems to be catching?